# Adding css properties to a table cell

Tags: css

I am trying to give some cells in a certain row in my table the same properties that the table header has. The cells that are supposed to look like the `<th>` are the ones tagged with the class `pag-row`. I am squeezing my braind trying to figure out why it's not working, maybe someone better at CSS can help me out. Here's the code:

```
table.tabla-foro
    {
        overflow:hidden;
        border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
        background:#fefefe;
        width:70%;
        margin: 0em auto 2em auto;
        -moz-border-radius:5px; /* FF1+ */
        -webkit-border-radius:5px; /* Saf3-4 */
        border-radius:5px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    table.tabla-foro th, table.tabla-foro td { padding:18px 28px 18px; text-align:center; }

    table.tabla-foro th, .pag-row { padding-top:20px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff; background:#e8eaeb; font-weight: bold; border-right: none; }

    table.tabla-foro td {border-top:1px solid #e0e0e0; border-right:1px solid #e0e0e0;}

    table.tabla-foro tr.odd-row td {background:#f6f6f6;}

    table.tabla-foro td.first, table.tabla-foro th.first {text-align:left}

    table.tabla-foro td.last {border-right:none;}


    table.tabla-foro td {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 25% 90deg, #fefefe, #f9f9f9);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 25%, from(#f9f9f9), to(#fefefe));
    }

    table.tabla-foro tr.odd-row td {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 25% 90deg, #f6f6f6, #f1f1f1);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 25%, from(#f1f1f1), to(#f6f6f6));
    }

    table.tabla-foro th, .pag-row {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 20% 90deg, #e8eaeb, #ededed);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 20%, from(#ededed), to(#e8eaeb));
    }



    table.tabla-foro tr:first-child th.first {
        -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    }

    table.tabla-foro tr:first-child th.last {
        -moz-border-radius-topright:5px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    }

    table.tabla-foro tr:last-child td.first {
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    }

    tr:last-child td.last {
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    }
```

Here goes the HTML too. Sorry for the tabulation, the table is generated with CodeIgniter.

```
<table class="tabla-foro" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<tr class="odd-row">
<th class="first">Post</th><th>Autor</th><th class="last">Último mensaje</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd-row">
<td class="first"><a href="http://localhost/erasmus/foro/lista#">Erasmus en España</a></td><td><a href="http://localhost/erasmus/foro/lista#">Carlos</a></td><td class="last"><a href="http://localhost/erasmus/foro/lista#">Pepe</a> a las 13:45 el 24/11/13</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="first">Erasmus en España</td><td>Carlos</td><td class="last">Pepe a las 13:45 el 24/11/13</td></tr>
<tr class="odd-row">
<td class="first">Erasmus en España</td><td>Carlos</td><td class="last">Pepe a las 13:45 el 24/11/13</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="first">Erasmus en España</td><td>Carlos</td><td class="last">Pepe a las 13:45 el 24/11/13</td></tr>
<tr class="odd-row">
<td class="first">Erasmus en España</td><td>Carlos</td><td class="last">Pepe a las 13:45 el 24/11/13</td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="pag-row first"><span class="paginacion icon icon-step-backward" onclick="alert(" ir="" al="" inicio")"=""></span>
                            <span class="paginacion icon icon-chevron-left" onclick="alert(" atras")"=""></span></td><td class="pag-row">1-10</td><td class="pag-row last" style="text-align: right"><span class="paginacion icon icon-chevron-right" onclick="alert(" siguiente")"=""></span>
                            <span class="paginacion icon icon-step-forward" onclick="alert(" ir="" al="" final")"=""></span></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?  Which CSS properties?  What is it doing instead?  What changes have you attempted?

Comment: The CSS is pretty useless without the HTML it targets.

Comment: Ok, I just updated the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem of specifity. Make the rule more specific and will score higher (and will win)

```
table.tabla-foro th, .tabla-foro tr .pag-row {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 20% 90deg, #e8eaeb, #ededed);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 20%, from(#ededed), to(#e8eaeb));
}
```